# Find overlaping rows and keep longest

Tags: python, arrays, awk

I want to edit a table based on overlaping values.

On column 1 I have a group name, on column 3 I have a start position value, and in column 4 is the end position.

I want to keep only rows with position values (start and end) that are not contained within the range of other rows of a given group (ex CE170_HUMAN).

For example, for CE170_HUMAN I have 6 rows, some of them have overlapping values: for example 165-523 (358 positions) range is contained within 1-523 range, I want to keep only the row with 1-523 as it covers a longer range (523 positions). Then do the same for the next group PURA2 and so on.

Input:

```
RAEG_00037367-RA        CE170_HUMAN   557     1584  
RAEG_00037368-RB        CE170_HUMAN   165     523    
RAEG_00037368-RA        CE170_HUMAN   326     523  
RAEG_00037368-RD        CE170_HUMAN   165     370  
RAEG_00037368-RC        CE170_HUMAN   1       523  
RAEG_00037368-RE        CE170_HUMAN   1       370  
RAEG_00037388-RB        PURA2_PIG     61      456  
RAEG_00037388-RC        PURA2_PIG     61      357  
RAEG_00037388-RA        PURA2_PIG     181     456  
RAEG_00037400-RA        KI26B_HUMAN   454     545  
RAEG_00037401-RA        KI26B_HUMAN   753     2108  
RAEG_00037415-RA        CNST_HUMAN    137     613  
RAEG_00037416-RA        CNST_HUMAN    637     725  
RAEG_00037420-RE        ELYS_HUMAN    1       2266
RAEG_00037420-RG        ELYS_HUMAN    1080    2266
RAEG_00037420-RF        ELYS_HUMAN    1       2266
RAEG_00037420-RD        ELYS_HUMAN    1080    2266
RAEG_00037420-RC        ELYS_HUMAN    205     2266
RAEG_00037420-RB        ELYS_HUMAN    1080    2266
```

Desired output

```
RAEG_00037367-RA        CE170_HUMAN   557     1584 
RAEG_00037368-RB        CE170_HUMAN   1       523 
RAEG_00037388-RC        PURA2_PIG     61      357 
RAEG_00037400-RA        KI26B_HUMAN   454     545 
RAEG_00037401-RA        KI26B_HUMAN   753     2108 
RAEG_00037415-RA        CNST_HUMAN    137     613 
RAEG_00037416-RA        CNST_HUMAN    637     725 
RAEG_00037420-RE        ELYS_HUMAN    1       2266
```

I am looking for a solution either on bash, perl or python.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try using the ```in``` keyword in conjunction with for loops.

Comment: @ericl16384 could you be more specific please? I am new on this type of coding.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by `longest` when you say `keep longest` and what you mean by `contained within` when  you say `are not contained within another row`. I cant tell if you're trying to do something by length of strings (and if so which strings) or numeric values of specific fields or something else.

Comment: @EdMorton I edited my question, hope is more comprenhesible now.

Comment: output should only have `PURA2_PIG     61      456`  for that key. If not so the logic is not well explained.

Comment: Hi @DianaMoSa it is highly encouraged that you show your own effort rather than just ask for someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your format, but I am sure you can adapt this:

```
rows = [
    "Hello",
    "World",
    "Hello World"
]

solution = []
found = False
for i in range(len(rows)):
    for j in range(len(rows)):
        if i == j:
            # Comparing equal things (will result in false positive)
            continue
        if str(rows[i]) in str(rows[j]):
            # Not a solution
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        # We have found a solution!
        solution.append(rows[i])
    else:
        # Not a solution. Resetting
        found = False

for i in solution:
    print(i)
```